# How to solve this simple definite Double integration

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{g(x)}{z(y)} \cdot \frac{f(x)}{f(y)} \: dx \: dy$

Here $f$ is the same function, the first time having x as domain, the second time with y as domain. Both $f$, $g$, and $z$ take values in range [0, 1].
I'm looking for a way to "get rid of" the $f$ function, both with x and y as domain.

Thanks!

Comment: The value is $(\int_0^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx)(\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {z(y)f(y)}dy)$ and cannot get rid of $f$.

Comment: In general, that's not possible. Sometimes, for specific functions, you can simplify double integrals like this. Do you know more about $f, g$ and $z$?

Comment: Are you given that $f,g\ge0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, both $f$, $g$, and $z$ take values in range [0, 1]